# As per checkbox selected from a popup window, redirection

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page with a button which open a popup window. This popup window has two checkboxes. if checkbox 1 is checked it should redirect to page1.php, if checkbox 2 is checked it should redirect to page2.php and if both the check boxes are checked it should redirect to page3.php. I have implemented this script in javascript and php.

The pop up window script is below:

```
 <html>
 <head>

<script language="Javascript">

    function redirectTo(){
        window.opener.location.href="grabvalues.php";
        self.close();
    }

</script>

<style>
 #checkboxes,
    #submit-button{
    display:none;
    }
</style>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 function rework(){
   document.getElementById("checkboxes").style.display = "block"
   document.getElementById("submit-button").style.display = "block"
   document.getElementById("rework-button").style.display = "none"

 }
 </script>


 </head>
 <body>


 <form method="POST">
    <input type="button" id="rework-button" value="Rework" onclick="rework()"/>

 <div id="checkboxes">
  Tech & Price: <input type="checkbox" id="techprice" name="techprice" value="techprice" />
  Terms & Conditions: <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="terms" />
 </div>


 <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Proceed" OnClick="redirectTo()"/>


 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The grabvalues.php script is below. i have problem in this php script

```
 <?php

    $techprice = $_POST['techprice'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];

    if ($techprice=1) {
   Redirect('page1.php', true);
    } 

     if ($terms=1) {
        Redirect('page2.php', true);
    } 

    if ($techprice=1 && $terms=1) {
    Redirect('page3.php', true);
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: you don't seem to be posting anything to `grabvalues.php`.

Comment: Am i making any mistake? How can i rectify it?

Comment: Actually Arun's solution will work. Other than that i think you should remove `window.opener.location.href="grabvalues.php";` from the script and add an `action` attribute to form.

Comment: Thank you. i will do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to submit the values to PHP

```
window.opener.location.href = "grabvalues.php?techprice=" + (techprice.checked ? 1 : 0) + '&terms=' + (terms.checked ? 1 : 0);
```

then your PHP code should be changed like

```
 <?php

    $techprice = $_GET['techprice'];
    $terms = $_GET['terms'];

    if ($techprice=1 && $terms=1) {
        Redirect('page3.php', true);
    } elseif ($techprice=1) {
        Redirect('page1.php', true);
    } elseif ($terms=1) {
        Redirect('page2.php', true);
    } 


 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. In the php code there is an error "Call to undefined function Redirect()"

Comment: @SujithNair that simply mean you don't have a function named Redirect in your PHP scope... where did you get the redirect code? the function should be there

Comment: I rectified it Arun. Thank you.

Comment: Need a small favour. How will append another querystring that is tender_id to the existing window.open ..    window.opener.location.href = "redirect_rework.php?techprice=" + (techprice.checked ? 1 : 0) + '&terms=' + (terms.checked ? 1 : 0);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $techprice = $_POST['techprice'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];

    if ($techprice ==1 && $terms==1) {
    Redirect('page3.php', true);
    }
    elseif ($techprice==1) {
        Redirect('page1.php', true);
    } 
    elseif ($terms==1) {
        Redirect('page2.php', true);
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
```